# Excel list with software names / How to get rid of similiar data?

Tags: excel, list, matching

I'm working on a huge list of software names in an excel file (10000+ rows). It looks something like this:

[image]

As you can see there is 7-zip with all kinds of versions and architecture types. Is there a way to filter these similar matches out? End-result would be that I only have one 7-zip entry in the list (doesn't matter how it looks like).

This is basically to see how many different applications are in the list - I'm not interested in the versions itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your image starts at row 37 so the following formula is set to start at row 37.

Paste this formula in column B and copy it down (and up if necessary) next to your data. It will strip everything from the end of your software name once it sees a number or an open parenthesis AFTER the third character. So 7-Zip is safe because the number 7 is within the first 3 characters.

Once you have the formulas in place, you can Remove Duplicates based on Column B.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A37,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"("},RIGHT(A37,LEN(A37)-3)&"0123456789("))+2),A37)
```